# Linkedin gem - Why does the API fetch different data sets on localhost and myDomain?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, linkedin-api, linkedin-gem

I wrote a code on my local machine to fetch linkedin full-profile data, the code is below. I have used the linkedin gem for the following code.

```
  @@config = { 
   :site => 'https://api.linkedin.com',
   :authorize_path => '/uas/oauth/authenticate',
   :request_token_path => '/uas/oauth/requestToken?scope=r_basicprofile+r_fullprofile+r_emailaddress+r_network',   
   :access_token_path => '/uas/oauth/accessToken' 
 }

client = LinkedIn::Client.new("myTokenxxxxxxxx", "mySecretxxxxxxx", @@config)
user_work_exs_linked_in = client.profile(:fields => [:positions]).positions
```

when I had registered my site for using the api on LinkedIn, I had entered both the localhost and the myDomain.com as the sites to be authorized.
Even though the linkedin information seems to be pulled in both cases, there is a difference in the object pulled out on my localhost as opposed to what is pulled out on my server session. For instance, the object "user_work_exs_linked_in" from above has the following structure in localhost:

```
=> #<LinkedIn::Mash all=[#<LinkedIn::Mash company=#<LinkedIn::Mash id=xxx industry="Internet" name="xxx" size="xxx" type="xxx"> id=xxx is_current=xxx start_date=#<LinkedIn::Mash month=x year=xxxx> summary="xxx" title="xxx">
```

whereas, it has a far more complex structure on the server as following (full structure not included as too long)

```
=> #<LinkedIn::Profile:0x007f0b8f5xxxxx @roxml_references=[#<ROXML::XMLTextRef:0x007f0b8f507340 @opts=#<ROXML::Definition:0x007f0b8ea6dc18 @default=nil, @to_xml=nil, @name_explicit=false, @cdata=nil, @required=nil, @frozen=nil, @wrapper=nil, @namespace=nil, @accessor="id", @array=false, @blocks=[], @sought_type=:text, @attr_name="id", @name="id">, @instance=#<LinkedIn::Profile:0x007f0b8fxxxxx ...>,..........
```

The object returned on localhost can be converted to hash whereas the object found on the server gives me an error if i call 'to_hash' on it.
what could be the reason for the server to be different from the localhost? Is this an authentication issue?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be an API authorization issue - i.e. localhost was authorized, yet myDomain was not. I regenerated a new api key under a new application name in LinkedIn... kaboom.. Now the world makes more sense.